# Working with multiple update panels and timer dedicated to specific updatepanel

Tags: c#, timer, c#-3.0, updatepanel

I have the code on master page as follows:

```
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="10000" ontick="Timer1_Tick"></asp:Timer> 
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updateNotifications" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
     <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
     </Triggers>
     <ContentTemplate>                                                        
        //Content                         
    </ContentTemplate>                        
   </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

This is working fine and refreshes the content with defined interval, but it also updates all the update panels on the content pages. I have to refresh only the content inside this update panel. I have tried `UpdateMode="Conditional"` and `UpdateMode="Always"` too but to no help.

Comment: i think you need to put the timer inside the updatePanel in order to update only that panel.. so <asp:Updated..> then <content> then <timer>

Comment: I have tried this but for same result.

Comment: there could be something wrong with the script manager then.. try using the default mark up from here [linl](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers) sorry i dont have access to an IDE atm to test.